# How to display custom dialog in Cocos2dxActivity

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, runtimeexception

How can I display a custom android dialog(with custom layout) in Cocos2dxActivity ?
I tried calling a method through JNI in which I created a Dialog, set its layout and displayed it.

```
public void displayDialog()
 {
    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
    d.setContectView(R.layout.myDialog);
    d.show();
 }
```

It gives me this error

`08-21 14:34:08.045: E/AndroidRuntime(2675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me is an Activity, in your case me = this; the key point is to use runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run(){}}

```
public void rateMe(String s){
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setTitle("Rate Me");

            dialog.setMessage("If you enjoy this game, please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
            //tv.setWidth(240);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Rate Now",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                int arg1) {
                            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.home.test")));
                        }

                    });

            dialog.setNegativeButton("No, thanks",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                int arg1) {

                        }
                    });       
            dialog.show();    
          }
    });
}
```